# Azure Pipelines - tests fail with Exit code 0xc0000142

Tags: c++, windows, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I use Azure DevOps pipelines for testing my C++ codes on several platform including windows.

One of my pipelines fails for tests on windows :

```
Test project D:/a/1/s/build/opengeodeio
Start 1: test-obj
1/3 Test #1: test-obj .........................Exit code 0xc0000142
***Exception:   0.14 sec
Start 2: test-ply
2/3 Test #2: test-ply .........................Exit code 0xc0000142
***Exception:   0.03 sec
Start 3: test-stl
3/3 Test #3: test-stl .........................Exit code 0xc0000142
***Exception:   0.03 sec

0% tests passed, 3 tests failed out of 3

Total Test time (real) =   0.32 sec

The following tests FAILED:
  1 - test-obj (Exit code 0xc0000142
)
  2 - test-ply (Exit code 0xc0000142
)
  3 - test-stl (Exit code 0xc0000142
)
Errors while running CTest
```

I search for this error code and it seems that it stands for  STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED. I have checked that all dlls are in the test folder.

I tried to reproduce that on my machine under windows without success (the tests passed on my machine).

Does anyone have an idea about that? What kind of tests/checks can I do? How to fix that?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: As you said that while you tried to reproduce on your machine under window but not success, does this mean that the test is successful on local machine but failed in Azure pipeline? Or in your local machine, the test still failed?

Comment: Yes, on my machine the tests are successful but there failed in Azure pipelines (I've edit my post to clarify this point)

Comment: Which agent do you use while run pipeline? Hosted agent? Or private agent? If using private agent, which mode does the agent using? Interactive or service mode?

Comment: I am using hosted (by Azure) agent with vmImage: "vs2017-win2016".